# How can I pick up all the titles and articles with scrapy?

Tags: python, django, xpath, scrapy

I'm currently on scraping some web information.
I don't know why but it just doesn't work fine.
It would be appreciated if someone could correct my code.

This is just an example but what I'd like to do here is from the starting URL, visit all the articles listed on it, and pick up the title and article from each. 
(all the articles come the way like `http://www.bbc.com/sport/tennis/42610656`)

Here is my code below.

Thanks so much for your help!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from myproject.NLP_items import Headline
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor




class BBC_sport_Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'sport'
    allowed_domains = ['www.bbc.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.bbc.com/sport/']
    allow_list = ['.*']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor( allow=allow_list), callback='parse_item'),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), follow=True),
    )


    def parse(self, response):

        for url in response.xpath('//div[@id="top-stories"]//a/@href').extract():
            yield(scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), self.parse_topics))

    def parse_topics(self, response):


        item=Headline()
        item["title"]=response.xpath('//div[@class="gel-layout__item gel-2/3@l"]//h1').extract()
        item["article"]=response.xpath('//div[@id="story-body"]//p').extract()


        yield item
```

`

Answer (score 0):

To quote the scrapy docs:

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.

So, by overwriting the `parse` method, you're invalidating the rules you've defined.

Also, `allow=['.*']` in a link extractor is a no-op, and so is a `follow=True` in a rule without a callback. If you want your rules to both parse an item and follow links, simply specify both a callback and follow instead of creating two rules.

Another problem is the `parse` method itself. The xpath inside it is selecting links from a div which doesn't exist (although a section with that id does).
However, if you're already using a `CrawlSpider`, you should specify an appropriate rule instead of overwriting `parse` in the first place.

And finally, I just want to note that `scrapy.contrib.spiders` and `scrapy.contrib.linkextractors` are deprecated; you should be using `scrapy.spiders` and `scrapy.linkextractors` instead.